# Radeon Pro WX 4130/4150 on Dell 7520

Tags: drivers, graphics, dell, radeon, amd-graphics

Hi trying to migrate from OSX to Ubuntu.  I have a Dell 7520 laptop with a Raedon Pro WX 4130/4150 and I'm trying to get the Video card to work in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.  AMD doesn't seem to have an official driver, are there any open source alternatives to get he card working.  It's kind of a deal breaker if I can't get it going.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WX 4130/4150 is fully supported in recent kernels with the `amdgpu` open-source drivers, which are the "official" AMD drivers.

https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=search&q=AMDGPU

Yours is the only path for 100% open-source drivers and excellent 3D acceleration. AMD still offers a "Pro" closed-source version of the driver with some secret sauce, but I have been ecstatic with the 2D and 3D performance of the open-source drivers.

Since Ubuntu lags behind on the latest kernel versions, you'll want to use a PPA repo for the latest drivers. I use the `oibaf` PPA with 16.04 LTS, which is the more conservative of a number of options described here: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ubuntu-1710-mesa&num=1 (dated article, but information still accurate).

tl;dr Add oibaf and enjoy your super-smooth hardware.